# Generate unique ids pairs

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate all possible unique ids pairs. Currently I'm trying to achieve it with two like that:

```
private prepareNewList(userIds: number[], existedPartnerList: string[]) {
    const newPartnerList = [];
    let usedUsersIds = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < userIds.length - 1; i++) {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < userIds.length; j++) {
        if (usedUsersIds.includes(userIds[i])) {
          continue;
        }

        const pair = ${userIds[i]}-${userIds[j]};
        const reversedPair = ${userIds[j]}-${userIds[i]};

        if (
          !existedPartnerList.includes(pair) &&
          !existedPartnerList.includes(reversedPair)
        ) {
          newPartnerList.push(pair);
          usedUsersIds.push(userIds[i], userIds[j]);

          break;
        }
      }
    }

    usedUsersIds = [];

    for (let i = userIds.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      for (let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (usedUsersIds.includes(userIds[j])) {
          continue;
        }

        const pair = ${userIds[i]}-${userIds[j]};
        const reversedPair = ${userIds[j]}-${userIds[i]};

        if (
          !existedPartnerList.includes(pair) &&
          !existedPartnerList.includes(reversedPair) &&
          !newPartnerList.includes(pair) &&
          !newPartnerList.includes(reversedPair)
        ) {
          newPartnerList.push(pair);
          usedUsersIds.push(userIds[i], userIds[j]);

          break;
        }
      }
    }

    return this.filterPairs(newPartnerList);
  }

private filterPairs(pairs: string[]): string[] {
    const usedIds = [];
    const pairsToRemove = [];
    pairs = pairs.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

    for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
      const parsedPair = pairs[i].split('-');

      if (parsedPair.some((id) => usedIds.includes(id))) {
        pairsToRemove.push(pairs[i]);
      }

      usedIds.push(...parsedPair);
    }

    return pairs.filter((item) => !pairsToRemove.includes(item));
  }
```

But it doesn't work properly. When I run the script for a first time I get `['1-2', '3-4', '5-6', '6-4', '5-3', '4-2', '3-1']` from first method and `[ '1-2', '3-4', '5-6' ]` after filtration, which is correct (because, for example, numbers from '6-4' pair have already been used in '3-4' and '5-6).

When I run the script for a second time I get `[ '1-3', '2-3', '4-5', '6-4', '5-3', '4-2' ]` from first method and  `[ '1-3', '4-5' ]` after filtration, which isn't correct, because there is one pair left `[ '6-2' ]` or `[ '2-6' ]`.

So my method doesn't work as I expect. What should I do to get this working?

**EDIT 1:**

I want to run this script every month to generate unique pairs of users. For example, in this month I've create pair 'user 1- user 2'. So in this month I can't use user 1 and user 2 anymore and can't use pair 'user 1- user 2' forever

**EDIT 2:**

Perhaps I explained incorrectly or not quite accurately. Every month I have to generate unique user pairs. For example, I have 6 users (there is always an even number), at the first start I can generate them as I want, because the table in the database is empty. For example: 1-2, 3-4, 5-6. The next month I run the script again and, suppose, the number of users has not changed, the existing pairs (1-2, 3-4, 5-6) are taken from the base and based on these existing pairs I must create new ones that will not be duplicates ( e.g. 1-4, 2-6, 3-5). And so every month + users will be added and, accordingly, the yield will increase.

Comment: Can you explain what the filtering is about if you are "trying to generate all possible unique ids pairs"?

Comment: Just a thought, if the ordering within a pair doesn't matter, it might be easier to concat them in sorted order so you can reliably check for a single value

Comment: @AKX filter transforms ['1-2', '3-4', '5-6', '6-4', '5-3', '4-2', '3-1'] into [ '1-2', '3-4', '5-6' ] (because, for example, numbers from '6-4' pair have already been used in '3-4' and '5-6)

Comment: @KyleMit can you provide an example pls?

Comment: Here's an [example of sorting the pair values](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/p02rnuoj/), which is similar to AKX's, but also don't think I've quite groked your requirements either

Comment: @KyleMit I want to run this script every month to generate unique pairs of users. For example, in this month I've create pair 'user 1- user 2'. So in this month I can't use user 1 and user 2 already and can't use pair 'user 1- user 2' forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Take 2 (no reuse)

If I understood the renewed requirements correctly, how about a recursive function like this?

```
function generatePairs(ids) {
  const uniqueIds = Array.from(new Set(ids));
  const results = [];
  function generateNext(idBag, pairs = []) {
    const [a, ...rest] = idBag;
    rest.forEach((b) => {
      const newPairs = [...pairs, [a, b]];
      const next = rest.filter((e) => e !== b);
      if (next.length >= 2) {
        generateNext(next, newPairs);
      } else {
        results.push({ pairs: newPairs, rest: next });
      }
    });
  }
  generateNext(uniqueIds);
  return results;
}
```

For an even number of users, e.g.

```
generatePairs(["John", "Mary", "Anne", "Zalgo", "Kenny", "Ben"]).forEach((result) => {
  console.log(result.pairs, result.rest);
});
```

the result is

```
[ [ 'John', 'Mary' ], [ 'Anne', 'Zalgo' ], [ 'Kenny', 'Ben' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Mary' ], [ 'Anne', 'Kenny' ], [ 'Zalgo', 'Ben' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Mary' ], [ 'Anne', 'Ben' ], [ 'Zalgo', 'Kenny' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Anne' ], [ 'Mary', 'Zalgo' ], [ 'Kenny', 'Ben' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Anne' ], [ 'Mary', 'Kenny' ], [ 'Zalgo', 'Ben' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Anne' ], [ 'Mary', 'Ben' ], [ 'Zalgo', 'Kenny' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Zalgo' ], [ 'Mary', 'Anne' ], [ 'Kenny', 'Ben' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Zalgo' ], [ 'Mary', 'Kenny' ], [ 'Anne', 'Ben' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Zalgo' ], [ 'Mary', 'Ben' ], [ 'Anne', 'Kenny' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Kenny' ], [ 'Mary', 'Anne' ], [ 'Zalgo', 'Ben' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Kenny' ], [ 'Mary', 'Zalgo' ], [ 'Anne', 'Ben' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Kenny' ], [ 'Mary', 'Ben' ], [ 'Anne', 'Zalgo' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Ben' ], [ 'Mary', 'Anne' ], [ 'Zalgo', 'Kenny' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Ben' ], [ 'Mary', 'Zalgo' ], [ 'Anne', 'Kenny' ] ] []
[ [ 'John', 'Ben' ], [ 'Mary', 'Kenny' ], [ 'Anne', 'Zalgo' ] ] []
```

and for an odd number (where we can't pair everyone up) the unpaired go in `rest`:

```
# ["John", "Mary", "Anne", "Zalgo", "Kenny"]

[ [ 'John', 'Mary' ], [ 'Anne', 'Zalgo' ] ] [ 'Kenny' ]
[ [ 'John', 'Mary' ], [ 'Anne', 'Kenny' ] ] [ 'Zalgo' ]
[ [ 'John', 'Anne' ], [ 'Mary', 'Zalgo' ] ] [ 'Kenny' ]
[ [ 'John', 'Anne' ], [ 'Mary', 'Kenny' ] ] [ 'Zalgo' ]
[ [ 'John', 'Zalgo' ], [ 'Mary', 'Anne' ] ] [ 'Kenny' ]
[ [ 'John', 'Zalgo' ], [ 'Mary', 'Kenny' ] ] [ 'Anne' ]
[ [ 'John', 'Kenny' ], [ 'Mary', 'Anne' ] ] [ 'Zalgo' ]
[ [ 'John', 'Kenny' ], [ 'Mary', 'Zalgo' ] ] [ 'Anne' ]
```

## Take 1 (all pairs, with reuse)

Wouldn't something like this do? It takes a little extra care to ensure the input doesn't have duplicates and to sort the result...

```
function generatePairs(ids) {
  const uniqueIds = Array.from(new Set(ids));
  const outSet = new Set();
  for (let i = 0; i < uniqueIds.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < uniqueIds.length; j++) {
      outSet.add(`${uniqueIds[i]}-${uniqueIds[j]}`);
    }
  }
  const out = Array.from(outSet);
  out.sort();
  return out;
}


console.log(generatePairs([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]));
```

The output is

```
[
  '1-2', '1-3', '1-4',
  '1-5', '1-6', '2-3',
  '2-4', '2-5', '2-6',
  '3-4', '3-5', '3-6',
  '4-5', '4-6', '5-6'
]
```

Comment: The problem is you can use one number one time. E.g if you create pair 1-2, you cant use these two numbers at all

Comment: @gachiKoKa Right, I see. Do you need _all_ possible pairing lists or just a single list of random pairings?

Comment: All possible I guess. For example, if you created 1-2, 2-1 is already incorrect. 
I want to store pairs in a database. Every month I want to run this script, pull out existing pairs to compare them with the ones I just created in order to avoid duplicates. In general, every month I need to create pairs that have not yet existed in the database.

Comment: @gachiKoKa Okay, see my edit! Would that work?

Comment: Not really I guess. Please see EDIT 2 in my post and thank you for helping me!

Comment: I think Take 2 will work for that; you'll just have to go through the pair sets generated by that function and ignore ones already in your database.